# SlickJS display issues on Safari, not Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, safari, slick.js

I have a page which uses SlickJS (http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/), which you can visit here: 
http://kitkittlegallery.com/category/organic-forms

This displays like so in Chrome: 
[image]

If you visit it in Safari, its display and functionality get destroyed. 
[image]

I have a feeling the issue is due to some of my own CSS conflicting with Slick's CSS or JS. Here's the JS used for this slick:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 


$('.slick-view').slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    speed: 500,
    draggable: false, 
    asNavFor: '.slick-nav',
    dots: false,
    centerMode: true,
    focusOnSelect: true,
    variableWidth: true, 
    autoplay: true, 
    autoplaySpeed: 5000,
    infinite: true, 
    arrows: false, 
});
$('.slick-nav').slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    speed: 500,
    draggable: false, 
    asNavFor: '.slick-view',
    dots: false,
    centerMode: true,
    focusOnSelect: true,
    variableWidth: true, 
    autoplay: true, 
    autoplaySpeed: 5000,
    infinite: true, 
    arrows: false, 
});
});
```

And the CSS:

```
 #slick *{ 
    transition: all .5s ease; 
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease; 
} 
#slick{
    width: 100%; 
    overflow: hidden;
}
.slick-view .slick-active{ 
    opacity: 1; 
} 
.slick-view .slick-slide:not(.slick-active){ 
    opacity: 0; 
} 
.slick-slide{ 
    cursor: pointer; 
} 
.viewer{ 
    width: 600px; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    margin: 1em auto; 
} 
.slick-view .slick-track img{ 
    max-height: 600px; 
    margin: 0em .5em;
    vertical-align: middle; 
} 
.viewer .slick-track img{ 
    max-height: 75px; 
    margin: 0em .5em; 
    opacity: .7; 
} 
.viewer .slick-track img.slick-active{ 
    opacity: 1 !important; 
} 
@media(max-width: 770px){ 
    .viewer{ 
        width: 100%; 
    } 
    .slick-view .slick-track img{ 
        max-height: 400px; 
    } 
} 
@media(max-width: 400px){ 
    .slick-view .slick-track img{ 
        max-height: 300px; 
    } 
}
```

Any red flags of things which might be causing conflicts?

Thanks in advance!